# Rolling updation with "kubectl apply" command

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

Currently I am practicing with Kubernetes resources like replicaSet , deployment and services. When I created my sample deployment and service for testing , I used `kube apply` command for creating the deployment and service into the Kubernetes cluster.That is properly working.

Now I am trying to make a end-to-end deployment using CI/CD pipeline. So when I am adding the deployment step in the `Jenkinsfile` , Can I use the `kube apply` command inside Jenkinsfile. Means If I am continuously committing in my SVN repo , changes will get update by using `kube apply` command? For each change I am making to repo need to reflect in deployment.

Can I use `kube apply` command for update also in Kubernetes ? Or Do I need to use `rollout` for updation of Kubernetes resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am continuously committing in my SVN repo , changes will get update by using kube apply command?
Ans:Yes

Below is the definition from kube document

> Apply is a command that will update a Kubernetes cluster to match
>   state defined locally in files.

https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/app_management/apply.html